# The redirected too many times error when use static HTML and removing trailing slashes

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use the following `.htaccess` code for static HTML pages, redirecting to HTTPS and non-www version and removing the trailing slashes

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ /$1.html [L]

# Redirect to https protocol
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Protocol} !=https
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

# Redirect from www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

# Redirect from URL with the trailing slash to the same URL without the slash
RedirectMatch ^(.+)/$ $1
```

But when I try to go to an inner page by the menu link without the trailing slash, the browser loads the page with the trailing slash like `mydomain.com/inner` and I get the error

> mydomain.com redirected you too many times.

**IMPORTANT!** I get the error only for the inner pages that have the directories with the same names. For example if I follow by link /category there is the `category.html` in the root directory and the `/category` directory with child HTML pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's enough to add in `.htaccess` as the first line

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

And to avoid `.html` in the address bar if we follow by link `/inner/` we also to move the redirect to HTTPS before all other rules